# Convert the following CURL PUT to test the JSON request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

How do I convert the following CURL PUT request to rspec and test the behaviour of JSON parser.

```
curl -D - -X PUT --data "not json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000
```

And how to check the response? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use vcr gem https://github.com/vcr/vcr

Simply create script like in https://github.com/vcr/vcr#usage but with proper HTTP request.

```
 VCR.use_cassette("json_test") do
   req = Net::HTTP::Put.new('http://localhost:3000', 'not json')
   req.content_type = 'application/json'
   res = Net::HTTP.get_response(req)
 end
```

With this real HTTP request will be recorded once and in rspec local file will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-i` option:

> **-i**, --include
>
> (HTTP) **Include the HTTP-header in the output**. The HTTP-header includes things like server-name, date of the document, HTTP-version and more...

from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html